# Gremlin 'except' usage doesnt seem to work

Tags: gremlin, titan

I am trying to find vertices except for some specific ones and this query below doesnt work:

```
 g.V()
.has('someId')
.except([g.V().has('someId').has('some_other_filter')])
```

Is this usage of 'except' where I provide it a query within it not correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [iterate your pipe](http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/pipe-iterate):

```
g.V()
.has('someId')
.except(g.V().has('someId').has('some_other_filter').toList())
```

without dumping what's in your `except` to a list you are actually just passing a pipeline to `except` which won't ever evaluate against a vertex as true.